# Reopen question on internal transfer interview

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

The question [Is it a good idea to take part in a transfer interview if I have no intention of accepting the job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/124500/is-it-a-good-idea-to-take-part-in-a-transfer-interview-if-i-have-no-intention-of) was recently closed for being a duplicate of [Should I go to an interview I don't intend to accept the job (if offered)?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/should-i-go-to-an-interview-i-dont-intend-to-accept-the-job-if-offered).

While I think the two questions are certainly similar, the new question is an interview for an internal position while the duplicate question is for a position at a separate company. I think the fact that this is for an internal interview makes the question significantly different and would change the answers begin given. I have nominated this question to be reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's fair.  I edited the question to make that distinction explicit (and link to the other question) and reopened.  Answerers should remember to address this specific property of the question (or answer the general one instead if they don't think it matters).